# Copy Values to another Spreadsheet with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I hope anyone can help me :)
I need the following function/scripttext for google appscript:

Copy the Value of cell A1 from spreadsheet 1 to cell A2 in spreadsheet 2.
So copy values from one to another spreadsheet per appscript.

Thank You Guys

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("spreadsheet 1");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("spreadsheet 2");
  var val = sheet1.getRange("A1").getValue();
  sheet2.getRange("A2").setValue(val) ;
}
```

Edit-- Above was my first answer, sorry I thought you meant copying cells within the same file, different sheets.  The one below is the one to copy to from a cell in this document, and paste it into another document that was shared with you:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("spreadsheet 1");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("paste URL here");
  var val = sheet1.getRange("A1").getValue();
  sheet2.getRange("A2").setValue(val) ;
}
```

sheet1 is the sheet you are copying from, sheet2 is the shared document, paste in the URL of the shared document where I wrote "paste URL here"

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you for your answer :) I think i used the wrong words. I want to copy the value from one to another document... So from File A in my private drive to File B in a shared drive. I hope you can help me :)

Comment: i want to select the document by ID

Comment: edited my code above.  Left the first one that copied data within the same file.  The bottom one is hopefully what you wanted, copying a cell from one document and pasting it to another document.  I shared a file with myself from another account to give it the full test, it all worked...  good luck

Comment: oh, you can open by id instead of url:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid